# U.K. visitor visa denied for being unable to confirm provenance

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

[image]

My partner recently got refused a U.K. visitor visa thinking that he has not got access to these funds even though he provided bank statements dated back to 6 months, an employment letter, a salary letter which are all in his name so I’m not really understanding what more evidence he can provide to get approved in his net application

Comment: Reading the attached I can see they highlighted other issues there too, they don't see why he would spend 4 months of living costs in just 14 days, they couldn't confirm where he works, or the amount he gets paid as he only submitted 1 payslip whereas the bank statements show varying amounts each month. The points that were made in the letter can all be addressed, more payslips. proof of working, possibly a break down of how he plans to spend 5k in only 14 days. If you can provide all these docs you could try to apply again, but if you can't solve the issues highlighted it will be denied again

Comment: I can understand the £5k in only 14 days part I think say around £3,000 would be more sufficient next time . But in Qatar they don’t really do payslips. He gave a proof of working which was an employment letter from HR and a letter from HR confirming his salary

Comment: The letter also states that the bank deposits do not appear to match his salary, and no explanation of this was provided. This is a serious problem, and it's what you should work on fixing first.

Comment: That was literally one bank deposit of £2,000  the other bank deposit that go into his savings are exactly £1000 each month that is transferred from his current account to his personal savings

Comment: His salary is £2,660 per month and he still lives at home with his parents in Qatar so transferring £1,000 to his saving per month for the last 11 months and leaving £1,660 in his current account for his living expenses is more than enough considering he lives with parents

Comment: @Hanna did he provide the statements for his current account (where he receives his salary) or of his savings account? He definitely needs to provide statements for his current account to prove his income (and the savings account to prove his savings).

Comment: While it is certainly possible to spend over 350 GBP a day as a tourist, I am not surprised this caused quite a few raised eyebrows when the person has such modest salary and funds. Take a look here https://www.budgetyourtrip.com/budgetreportadv.php?geonameid=2643743&countrysearch=&country_code=&categoryid=0&budgettype=2&triptype=0&startdate=&enddate=&travelerno=0

Comment: Yeah he did provide two bank statements one from his current account and one from his savings account. And he submitted a employment contract and shown his salary contractbso I don’t know what more evidence he can provide to prove that the money is his money when everything is in his name

Comment: If his salary varies each pay period due to bonuses, deductions, different hours worked, he needs to document that. Additionally, he should deposit his entire payment, then withdraw money for expenses.Let's say he makes $12000 / year. They want to see $1000 added to the account each month. If it's not $1000, explain why.